# Python issue with list and join function

Tags: python, list, for-loop, queue

How do I append two digit integer into a list using for loop without splitting them. For example I give the computer 10,14,13,15 and I get something like 1,0,1,4,1,3,1,5. I tried to go around this, but I ended up with a new issue, which is Type Error: sequence item 0: expected string, int found

```
def GetNumbers(List):
    q=[]
    Numberlist = []

    for i in List:
        if i.isdigit():
            q.append(int(i))
        else:
            Numberlist.append(''.join(q[:]))
            del q[:]

    return Numberlist
```

Comment: Your modifying a list while iterating over it; Something you should never do.

Comment: also there's no need for `del q[:]`, since no variable refers to it the first time it was used, it has already been garbage collected

Comment: I am modifying a temporary list, and that's for appending a number that is not a single digit, like if you have 10 in a list and you do a for loop over the list the computer will read it as 1 and 0 instead of 10

Comment: what is your expected input and output data type ? is't a list of string ? list of integer ? or a string with comma ?

Answer (score 0):

Ideal way will be to use `str.split()` function as:

```
>>> my_num_string = "10,14,13,15"
>>> my_num_string.split(',')
['10', '14', '13', '15']
```

But, since you mentioned you can not use `split()`, you may use `regex` expression to extract numbers from string as:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.findall('\d+', my_num_string)
['10', '14', '13', '15']
```

Else, if you do not want to go with any fancy method, you may achieve it with simple `for` loop as:

```
num_str, num_list = '', []
#  ^ Needed for storing the state of number while iterating over
#    the string character by character

for c in my_num_string:
    if c.isdigit():
       num_str += c
    else:
       num_list.append(num_str)
       num_str = ''
```

---

The numbers in `num_list` will be in the form of `str`. In order to convert them to `int`, you may explicitly convert them as:

```
num_list = [int(i) for i in num_list]  # OR, list(map(int, num_list))
```